# How can I modify this query so that I can sort the results by the number of comments each post has?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been stuck on this for about a week. have an SQL query that fetches posts from a database. I need to add a LEFT JOIN that will allow me to order the posts by the number of comments each post has. From the post with the most comments to the least comments. This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    wallposts.p_id,
    wallposts.is_profile_notes,
    wallposts.times_viewed,
    wallposts.columnTimesShared,
    wallposts.marked,wallposts.secure_id,
    wallposts.reshared,wallposts.group_id,
    wallposts.totaluploads,
    wallposts.WallUploadID,
    wallposts.type,
    wallposts.value,
    wallposts.media,
    wallposts.youtube,
    wallposts.post_type,
    wallposts.privacy,
    wallposts.tagedpersons,
    wallposts.with_friends_tagged,
    wallposts.emotion_head,
    wallposts.selected_emotion,
    wallposts.title,
    wallposts.url,
    wallposts.description,
    wallposts.cur_image,
    wallposts.uip,
    wallposts.likes,
    wallposts.userid,
    wallposts.posted_by,
    wallposts.post as postdata,
    wallusers.*, 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - wallposts.date_created AS TimeSpent,
    PosterTable.mem_pic as posterPic,
    PosterTable.gender as posterGender,
    PosterTable.oauth_uid as poster_oauth_uid,
    PosterTable.username as posterUsername, 
    PosterTable.mem_fname as posterFname,
    PosterTable.work as posterWork, 
    PosterTable.mem_lname as posterLname,
    walllikes_track.id as PostLikeFound,
    wallposts.date_created
FROM 
    wallusers,
    wallusers as PosterTable,
    wallposts 
LEFT JOIN
    walllikes_track
ON
    wallposts.p_id = walllikes_track.post_id
AND 
    walllikes_track.member_id = ".$user_id." 
WHERE
    wallusers.active = 1 
AND
    PosterTable.active = 1
AND
    wallposts.group_id IN (".$groups.")
AND
    wallposts.group_id != 0
AND
    PosterTable.mem_id = wallposts.posted_by
AND
    wallposts.marked < ".$this->flagNumber."
AND
    wallusers.mem_id = wallposts.posted_by
```

"wallposts" is the name of the table with my posts and has a p_id. And "wallcomments" is the name of the table that has the comments in it with a column called post_id to link it to posts. Please help I need to order the posts by the number of comments. I have tried this but my screen goes blank and my program crashes every time:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    wallposts.p_id,
    wallposts.is_profile_notes,
    wallposts.times_viewed,
    wallposts.columnTimesShared,
    wallposts.marked,wallposts.secure_id,
    wallposts.reshared,wallposts.group_id,
    wallposts.totaluploads,
    wallposts.WallUploadID,
    wallposts.type,
    wallposts.value,
    wallposts.media,
    wallposts.youtube,
    wallposts.post_type,
    wallposts.privacy,
    wallposts.tagedpersons,
    wallposts.with_friends_tagged,
    wallposts.emotion_head,
    wallposts.selected_emotion,
    wallposts.title,
    wallposts.url,
    wallposts.description,
    wallposts.cur_image,
    wallposts.uip,
    wallposts.likes,
    wallposts.userid,
    wallposts.posted_by,
    wallposts.post as postdata,
    wallusers.*, 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - wallposts.date_created AS TimeSpent,
    PosterTable.mem_pic as posterPic,
    PosterTable.gender as posterGender,
    PosterTable.oauth_uid as poster_oauth_uid,
    PosterTable.username as posterUsername, 
    PosterTable.mem_fname as posterFname,
    PosterTable.work as posterWork, 
    PosterTable.mem_lname as posterLname,
    walllikes_track.id as PostLikeFound,
    wallposts.date_created,

    p.p_id,
    c.postcount

FROM 
    wallusers,
    wallusers as PosterTable,
    wallposts,
    wallposts as p


INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT
                    post_id,
                    count(*) AS postcount
                FROM
                    wallcomments
                GROUP BY
                    post_id
            ) as c
on
    p.p_id = c.post_id


LEFT JOIN
    walllikes_track
ON
    wallposts.p_id = walllikes_track.post_id
AND 
    walllikes_track.member_id = ".$user_id." 
WHERE
    wallusers.active = 1 
AND
    PosterTable.active = 1
AND
    wallposts.group_id IN (".$groups.")
AND
    wallposts.group_id != 0
AND
    PosterTable.mem_id = wallposts.posted_by
AND
    wallposts.marked < ".$this->flagNumber."
AND
    wallusers.mem_id = wallposts.posted_by
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try doing it in the opposite direction

```
select a.post_id, ...all the rest ... 
from 
   (select post_id, count(1) as c from  wallcomments group by 1 order by 2 desc) a
left join wallcomments w on w.p_id = a.post_id ...
```

`group by` and `order by` with column indexes/numbers instead of column names should work fine at least with MySQL and Oracle, maybe others too

What I'm trying to say is that in your query you are trying to "get everything from many tables" and then sort by "some data in another table", what might help is to focus first on getting a list of post_ids sorted by the number of comments, as you wanted, then "enrich" each record ( by joining on the post_id) with data from the other tables.

Also you could create a view on the comments table which shows only post_ids, no_of_comments

**Later edit:** after taking a better look at your query, it seems to me that it  has some things that don't add up ... for example, why are you using the wallusers table twice ? you seem to link to it on the same way (maybe I've lost something), anyway after some fiddling I came up with this

```
SELECT 
    c.*, -- the "count collection" data (also ensures distinct post_id, because it has group by
    p.*, -- posts fields
    u.*, -- user data
    l.* -- likes data
FROM 
    (select post_id, COUNT(1) as comment_count FROM  wallcomments GROUP BY post_id) as c
    LEFT JOIN wallposts as p on p.p_id = c.post_id
    LEFT JOIN wallusers as u on u.mem_id = p.posted_by
    LEFT JOIN walllikes_track as l on l.post_id = p.p_id
WHERE 
    l.member_id = ".$user_id." AND
    p.group_id IN (".$groups.") AND
    p.marked < ".$this->flagNumber."
ORDER BY c.comment_count DESC
```

you'll have to tweak it in order to get the desired list of columns and to add the any other conditions.

As a side note, look into "Prepare Statements" instead of building and executing a raw query (also check SQL-Injection)

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer. I am about to try it now. Does "a.post_id" refer to the id of the comments? Is that the only thing I would need add to the select clause?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it was (very) late in my timezone when I've first replied. I've added some extra details on the original response. Answering to the question...a.post_id would be the "post_id" column from the comments table. (Answering from the phone is a real pain...)

Comment: No worries. I appreciate your efforts. Yea I tried doing it in reverse and the same thing keeps happening. The program crashes. I wonder if it is because I am using SELECT DISTINCT.... hmmm

Comment: Maybe it's too much data... You could add EXPLAIN before the SELECT to see how the query is processed... maybe it will give you some hint on was going wrong ...

Comment: I have never heard of EXPLAIN. I will look into it. Thank you for the suggestion. There is such a thing as too much data in a query? Wow I didn't know that either. Maybe you're right.